# Backbone.js - don't render view/template again

Tags: view, controller, render, backbone.js

In my app I have a list of products and when you click on a product, a [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) opens to show the product details.

Now when the user closes the Fancybox, I change the URL back from '#/product-name' to '#' and the list of products is rendered again, even though it is already there.

My question is:

**How do I avoid the product list from being rendered again?**

So somewhere either in the list action of my controller or the list view I want to check if the product list is already rendered and don't render it again.

It feels like something that should be possible to accomplish quite easily but I can't get it right.

All ideas appreciated!

EDIT: edited for clarification

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work (so I'm just adding it as a comment): instead of `window.location.replace('');` how about `window.history.back();`?

Comment: This would probably work, but I can't see how that would solve my problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at backbone:s saveLocation method. It doesn't trigger a hashchange event.

Comment: Works great! Now I finally know what saveLocation is for.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to change the hash part of your url.

```
window.location.hash = ""
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! The end result is the same, though: the index view is rendered again. How do I avoid that?